# Java binding for LMDB, need help to refresh LMDB JNI

Tags: java-native-interface, lmdb

we are using LMDB within java application.
The Java bindings that are available are 1 year old.
I would like to refresh the LMDBJNI
https://github.com/chirino/lmdbjni

However, the project owner, did not provide any instructions on how to build his project.
So I cannot just clone his git repository, and drop the new version of LMDB ( https://git.gitorious.org/mdb/mdb.git ) c and h files, and get it rebuilt

It seems that underneath LMDB JNI Is using hawkjni, but that's as far as I had gotten.

these are the steps I tried

a) git clone https://github.com/chirino/lmdbjni.git
b) cd lmdbjni;  mvn install
It finishes successfully, however the resulting JAR does not have the actual lmdb library compiled.
So my test program fails with

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no lmdbjni64-99-vspmaster-SNAPSHOT in java.library.path, no lmdbjni-99-vspmaster-SNAPSHOT in java.library.path, no lmdbjni in java.library.path]
    at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:182)
    at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:140)
    at org.fusesource.lmdbjni.JNI.<clinit>(JNI.java:41)
    at org.fusesource.lmdbjni.Env.create(Env.java:42)
    at org.fusesource.lmdbjni.Env.<init>(Env.java:36)
    at com.db.locrefdcache.App.main(App.java:27)
    ... 6 more
```

c) then I figured, I may not just be able to run mvn install for lmdbjni, and instead I need to explicitly build it's 64 bit Linux subsystem

so I did
cd lmdbjni/lmdbjni-linux64
mvn install

There I can I see that its trying to run configure  script (generated by autotools), but I get the

```
...
[INFO] checking lmdb.h usability... no
[INFO] checking lmdb.h presence... no
[INFO] checking for lmdb.h... no
[INFO] configure: error: cannot find headers for lmdb
[INFO] rc: 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
```

So what I do not quite understand is whether lmdb files (lmdb.h , mdb.c, midl.h ) need to be explicitly dropped somewhere, or if hawkjni actually needs to be ran prior on them and create some sort of 'intermediate' c and h files that later on get dropped into this build environment.

---

Update with Compile Error I am getting, when using the LMDBJNI deephacks fork
Reason for recompile: DeepHacks's LMDBJNI project had produced a maven archive for LMDBJNI with latest LMDB, however it was compiled with Java 8 (which we do not yet use).  So I need to recompile it with Java 7.

I modified pom.xml and changed Sources 1.8 to  1.7
Then, mvn install -P linux64  produces an error

```
...
[INFO] [hawtjni:build {execution: default}]
[INFO] Extracting /home/dev01/.m2/repository/org/deephacks/lmdbjni/lmdbjni/0.1.3-SNAPSHOT/lmdbjni-0.1.3-SNAPSHOT-native-src.zip to /home/dev01/devel/3dp/lmdbjni/lmdbjni-linux64/target/native-build-extracted
[INFO] executing: /bin/sh -c make install
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] build failed: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Make based build did not generate: /home/dev01/devel/3dp/lmdbjni/lmdbjni-linux64/target/native-build/target/lib/liblmdbjni.so
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might have better luck with this fork, which is actively being maintained

https://github.com/deephacks/lmdbjni

They've also provided LMDB itself in Maven, you can see how that was setup here

https://github.com/deephacks/lmdb

Comment: Unfortunately the linux-64 bit maven jar compiled for Java 8. I was getting "  Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 " error when running my test.  So I got brave and tried to recompile this lmdbjni fork by myself with Java 7.  I went to pom.xml and modified the <source> tag to be 1.7 (instead of 1.8).  That let me compile the lmdbjni-0.1.3-SNASHOT.jar with Java 7.  But I still cannot compile lmdbjni-linux64  which is the the jar that includes the actual 64 bit native code of your database. I will keep fighting though :-).

Answer (score 1):

It builds fine on my machine with Java 7. Did you provide the correct profile when building the packages? For linux you must use: mvn install -P linux64

Comment: No not compiling for me. I am getting

Comment: I am getting build error. I had updated my original question with the error inf

Comment: hawtjni depends on automake and libtool (sudo apt-get install build-essential automake1.10 libtool) do you have those installed?

Comment: Yes, I have automake (v 1.13.4) and libtool (v 2.4.2) installed.  For some reason I am thinking (and I may be totally wrong) that pom.xml in linux64 is referring to directories that do not get created. I cannot verify this, as I do not understand how the maven processing jumps from that pom definition to the " executing: /bin/sh -c make install".  Another approach, if you can make the build with java 1.7 and push into the maven, and people like us would just then get the pre-compiled version (although figuring out build issue, would be much safer for us).

Comment: Yes that might be one way forward, lmdbjni doesn't require java 8 after all. Ill see if I can deploy a 1.7 version tomorrow and maybe we  can work out the build issue later.

Comment: I just deployed version 0.2.0 which use Java 7. Should be available in Maven Central in a couple of hours. Let me know if this release works for you.

Comment: Thank you. 0.2.0 works for Java 7.  Let me know how/when you can troubleshoot the build issue.